# Errors when creating invoice + Invoice module

Tags: nodes, rules, users, commerce

I'm having trouble creating invoices with the [Invoices module](https://drupal.org/project/invoice). I want to create an invoice for the user when he is registrating. The problem is I need to generate an invoice and fill in the values, but I don't know how to do this.

I have created a Rule with the [Rules module](https://drupal.org/project/rules). My rule looks like this:

[image]
[image]

The problem is now when I want to registrate I get this errors:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$invoice_number in invoice_node_presave() (line 437 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xmed_dp/sites/all/modules/invoice/invoice.module).

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$user_defined_invoice_number in invoice_node_presave() (line 439 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xmed_dp/sites/all/modules/invoice/invoice.module).

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$invoice_invoice_number_zerofill in _invoice_get_formatted_invoice_number() (line 410 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xmed_dp/sites/all/modules/invoice/invoice_helpers.inc).

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$invoice_invoice_number_prefix in _invoice_get_formatted_invoice_number() (line 411 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xmed_dp/sites/all/modules/invoice/invoice_helpers.inc).

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$template in invoice_insert() (line 784 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xmed_dp/sites/all/modules/invoice/invoice.module).

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$invoice_description in invoice_insert() (line 797 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xmed_dp/sites/all/modules/invoice/invoice.module).

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$pay_limit in invoice_insert() (line 799 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xmed_dp/sites/all/modules/invoice/invoice.module).
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'tid' at row 1: INSERT INTO {invoice_invoices} (iid, nid, leading_zeros, prefix, description, tid, pay
```

How can I make sure these values are generated?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bugreport for Invoice module. Bugs found on modules, Drupal itself, or Drupal.org (and its sub-domains) should be reported in the appropriate issue queue on Drupal.org.

Comment: Don't think it's a bug. I'm justing doing something wrong ...

Comment: But it shouldn't really be possible to do something that wrong via GUI?..

Comment: But how is it possible that I can create an invoice when registrating a user without adding data to the invoice? Where does he get the data?

Comment: OK, vote retracted. But I still think it's not quite OK that module allowed creation of faulty rule. Problem seems interesting...